# Quebrar linha em texto de link com &text

Tags: html

Como realizar uma quebra de linha depois da palavra `inicial`

```
<a>https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seu-numero&text=Mensagem Inicial</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o caractere de [controle ASCII](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_4/cfg_fund/command/reference/cfnapph.html) `%0D` (*carriage return*):

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=seu-numero&text=Mensagem Inicial%0DNova linha">mensagem</a>
```

Isso irá fazer uma quebra de linha na posição que você quiser.

Comment: dvd funcionou, como gostaria apenas que o cursor do usuário estivesse logo abaixo sem necessidade de ter algo depois da quebra de linha, ficou assim `%0D%20` adicionei um espaço, a não ser que tenha outra forma

Comment: Coloque 2x `%0D`: `&text=Mensagem Inicial%0D%0D`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Não entendi.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não entendi

Comment: @dvd É mesmo, bastava colocar duas vezes, kkk

Answer (score 4):

O `%0D` pode até funcionar no campo de inserção do texto no WhatsApp WEB, mas não vai respeitar.

**O correto é o `%0A`**